# Get the RouteBuilder class used at execution time

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to retrieve what `RouteBuilder` class was used to build a Route at execution time via the `Exchange`? For example;

```
class SimplePingRoute : RouteBuilder() {
override fun configure() {
    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=1000")
        .routeId("pong-demo-app")
        .process({exc->
            //***looking for SimplePingRoute at this point from exc*** 
        })
        .to("log:pong")
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel 3.20 onwards stores the source file:line-number of the routes for each EIP node (you need to enable this for Java DSL). This allows tooling such as the debugger to correlate the runtime debug session with the source code. And tooling like camel-jbang to output source precise information.

Maybe your tool can use that also.

Answer (score 0):

A Java example, but easily transformed to your language of choice:

```java
.process(exchange -> {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
})
```

Comment: thanks but "at execution time via the Exchange" is the critical part to the question.

Comment: this is at execution time. And the exchange does not store the name of a RouteBuilder.

Comment: Thanks - this approach can only ever works for lamdas processors hence the reason i've been explicit around retrieving from the exchange..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the routebuilder in an exchange property, so that it is always available in the later processing ?

```
 from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=1000")
        .routeId("pong-demo-app")
        .setProperty("routeBuilder").constant( this.getClass().getName() )
        .process( exc-> System.out.println(exc.getProperty("routeBuilder")) )
        .to("log:pong")
```

Comment: Thanks - The rationale for this is because i'm developing an external Library that has logic contained within the Processor contract so reducing the boilerplate is my aspiration & didn't put this as part of the question as to keep the question succinct.